Why Timeout Exception has "Operation cancelled by user." even though user didn't do anything?
I am getting the following SQL Exception in an ASP.NET app in production environment:

Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
completion of the operation or the server is not responding. Operation
cancelled by user.

Why am I getting "Operation cancelled by user", as I don't get this in my debug environment neither there is a way to stop query execution manually?
My query does have a timeout time which I just kept 5 sec to throw the timeout error in my debug environment? Please help why "Operation cancelled by user." is shown ?
FYI: I am using SQL Server
Failed attempts to raise the same error:

I did all the possible timeout constraint settings in SSMS to throw error with "Operation cancelled by user" but it didn't happen.
I modified the timeout of my query to throw the error in my debug environment but still didn't get the exact error mentioning "Operation cancelled by user".


"Operation cancelled by user" is just the error message, it means from the perspective of the server, the client cancelled, rather than an error happening. It's the equivalent of clicking the Stop button in SSMS after 5 seconds.
